# Get Tag names of a JSON string

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse JSON string using JSONParser class. Can anybody help figuring out how to get the tag name also. For example take this string:

```
{ people:{[ name: John, age: 27],[name: Alen, gender: female]}}
```

If I have an object containing name "John" and age "27", how can I get the tag names, like in this case are name and age?

Comment: Which JSON parsing library are you using? I bet it has some online documentation.

Comment: Consider providing an example string that is valid JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using some existent library, I guess [quick-json](https://code.google.com/archive/p/quick-json). In order to get a Map (that you can later iterate through `map.entrySet()`) you can do:

```
JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
Map map=parser.parseJson(jsonString);
```

Also take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) for more information on other libraries.